# Efficiently traversing array matching a boolean condition?

Tags: arrays, scala

This is another question from `Scala for the Impatient` which says

> Write a function lteqgt(values: Array[Int], v: Int) that returns a
>   triple containing the counts of values less than v, equal to v, and
>   greater than v.

The way I have done that is

```
scala> def lteqgt(values: Array[Int], v: Int): (Int, Int, Int) = (values.count(_ < v), values.count(_ == v), values.count(_ > v))
lteqgt: (values: Array[Int], v: Int)(Int, Int, Int)

scala> lteqgt(Array(0,0,1,1,1,2,2), 1)
res47: (Int, Int, Int) = (2,3,2)
```

**Problem?**
I am traversing the array `3` times to collect the counts, Is there a way to collect the values in first go? an idiomatic way?

Answer (score 10):

This is perfect case to use `foldLeft`. It will traverse your collection exactly once, without creating another collection (as `groupBy` does) and it's more concise comparing to the more generic `aggregate`.

```
def lteqgt(values: Array[Int], v: Int): (Int, Int, Int) =
  values.foldLeft((0, 0, 0)) {
    case ((lt, eq, gt), el) =>
      if (el < v) (lt + 1, eq, gt)
      else if (el == v) (lt, eq + 1, gt)
      else (lt, eq, gt + 1)
  }
```

If you want to achieve ultimate efficiency, while avoiding imperative approach, then tail-recursion is the way to go:

```
def lteqgt(values: Array[Int], v: Int): (Int, Int, Int) = {
  def rec(i:Int, lt:Int, eq:Int, gt:Int):(Int, Int, Int) =
    if (i == values.length) (lt, eq, gt)
    else if (values(i) < v) rec(i + 1, lt + 1, eq, gt)
    else if (values(i) == v) rec(i + 1, lt, eq + 1, gt)
    else rec(i + 1, lt, eq, gt + 1)
  rec(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

This avoids construction `Tuple` and boxed Ints on each iteration. The whole thing compiles to `while` loop in java ([here is the transpiled output](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/7adecb7107ea1b164187) if you are interested).

Answer (score 2):

While a functional solution is arguably more elegant, let's not forget the "boring" but efficient imperative solution.

```
def lteqgt(values: Array[Int], v: Int): (Int, Int, Int) = {
    var lt = 0
    var eq = 0
    var gt = 0
    values.foreach (i => {
      if      (i<v)  lt += 1
      else if (i==v) eq += 1
      else           gt += 1
    })
    (lt,eq,gt)
  }
```

The above is likely to generate one function call per loop, as Aivean points out below. For more efficiency, we can remove the closure manually. (It's a pity that such optimization is not yet done by the compiler, though)

```
 def lteqgt(values: Array[Int], v: Int): (Int, Int, Int) = {
   var lt = 0
   var eq = 0
   var gt = 0
   var i = 0
   while (i < values.length) {
     if      (values(i) < v ) lt += 1
     else if (values(i) == v) eq += 1
     else                     gt += 1
     i += 1
   }
   (lt,eq,gt)
  }
```

Comment: It may not be as efficient as it appears. Compare [your code transpiled to java](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/2873001fec4507dce257) to the [tail-recursive solution](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/7adecb7107ea1b164187). I haven't benchmarked it, but I think function call for each iteration might be less efficient.

Comment: You probably wanted to use `while` loop. Scala doesn't support java-style `for` loop. Scala's `for` loop compiles into `foreach`/`map`.

Comment: @Aivean Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @chi's, but let's exceed the design spec a wee bit so we can compare other data besides Ints.  And the title says "Traversing" so let's use a [Traversable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable) so we can analyze all other collections.  The machine may not execute this faster, but it might be programmer-time efficient.

```
def lteqgt[T](values:Traversable[T], v:T)(implicit cmp: Ordering[T]):(Int,Int,Int) =  {
            var l = 0;
            var e = 0; 
            var g = 0;
            for(x <- values){
                if (cmp.equiv(v,x)) e += 1
                else if (cmp.gt(x,v)) g += 1
                else l += 1
            }
        (l,e,g);
};
```

Usage:

```
scala> lteqgt(List(1.0,2.0,3.0,2.5), 2.5)
res0: (Int, Int, Int) = (2,1,1)

scala> lteqgt(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0,2.5), 2.5)
res1: (Int, Int, Int) = (2,1,1)

scala> lteqgt(Vector(1.0,2.0,3.0,2.5), 2.5)
res2: (Int, Int, Int) = (2,1,1)

scala> lteqgt(Set(1.0,2.0,3.0,2.5), 2.5)
res3: (Int, Int, Int) = (2,1,1)

scala> lteqgt(1 to 100, 45)
res4: (Int, Int, Int) = (44,1,55)

scala> lteqgt(Range(0,100,3), 50)
res5: (Int, Int, Int) = (17,0,17)

scala> lteqgt(List("fee","fie","foe","fum"), "foo")
res6: (Int, Int, Int) = (3,0,1)

scala> lteqgt(None, 1)
res7: (Int, Int, Int) = (0,0,0)

scala> lteqgt(Some(2), 1)
res8: (Int, Int, Int) = (0,0,1)
```